# ¿cual es la funcionalidad de String double quoted en PHP?

Tags: php

Mientras leía un articulo de PHP, vi el tipo de `string php double quoted` y me dio curiosidad saber como funciona mientras leía su documentación en inglés en PHP.

[fuente](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

no encontré mucha información sobre el , un `String double quoted` es sencillamente un `String` simple y corriente o tiene alguna funcional especial o adicional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia entre un `string` envuelto entre comillas simples y otro envuelto entre comillas dobles es que el de comillas simples siempre va a ser interpretado como un literal y el de dobles va a ser primero revisado por el intérprete para comprobar si debe o no debe interpretar algo en su interior.

Esto puede sonar algo confuso pero con un ejemplo quedará bastante más claro:

**Uso de comillas simples**

```
$nombre = 'Pepe';

echo 'Mi nombre es $nombre';
```

Resultado:

> Mi nombre es $nombre

**Uso de comillas dobles**

```
$nombre = 'Pepe';

echo "Mi nombre es $nombre";
```

> Mi nombre es Pepe

Como ves, con el uso de las comillas simples el intérprete entiende que dentro de ellas no existe algo que deba interpretar, por lo que el nombre de la variable se escribe literalmente como si se tratase de una palabra más.

En el caso de las dobles, si que comprueba lo que hay en su interior, encontrando la variable `$nombre` y obteniendo su valor.

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el enlace que provees en tu misma pregunta, existen 2 escenarios principales **(aunque no son los únicos)**

**Escenario 1**

> Lo que se escriba dentro de comillas simples y sea dinámico, por ejemplo:

- saltos de línea
- variables
- constantes

se interpretará de manera literal, es decir no va a existir interpolación de los datos y interpretación del símbolo de salto de línea por ejemplo.

**Ejemplo de escenario 1**

El siguiente script se ejecuta desde la consola y se comporta del modo siguiente:

1. Declaro una variable que contiene la edad, así: `$edad = 20`

---

```
$edad = 23;
```

2. Imprimimos dicha variable dentro de una sentencia `echo`, tratando de aplicarle un salto de línea del modo siguiente:

---

```
php > $edad = 23;
php > echo 'Tu edad es \n $edad';
Tu edad es \n $name
```

> Como puedes notar, no existe interpretación del contenido de la variable por lo cual no la interpola y tampoco aplica el salto de línea.

**Escenario 2**

De la documentación:

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.

Que se pudiera traducir como:

> Cuando una cadena se específica en comillas dobles o con `heredoc`, las variables son parseadas dentro de ella:

- saltos de línea
- variables
- constantes

se interpola o se interpreta de manera dinámica, visualizándolo en el resultado impreso desde la consola o desde el navegador .

**Ejemplo de escenario 2**

Repitiendo el mismo ejercicio del escenario 1, obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
php > $edad = 20;
php > echo "Tu edad es \n $edad";
Tu edad es
 20
```

**Extra**

Puedes también dentro de una impresión de valores, encerrar una variable dentro de `{}` pero no deben existir espacios vacíos entre estas y la variable a interpolar.

```
php > $edad = 20;
php > echo "Tu edad es \n {$edad}";
Tu edad es
 20
```

**¿Qué pasa con los valores `CONSTANTES`?**

A diferencia de las variables, las constantes no cuentan con un símbolo que el intérprete de PHP pueda tomar como referencia para llevar a cabo el proceso de interpolación e imprimir el valor que tiene asociado.

**Ejemplo**

```
php > DEFINE('INCREMENTO', 20);
php > echo "El valor del incremento es de: INCREMENTO";
El valor del incremento es de: INCREMENTO
```

Como se puede observar no se interpreta el valor de la constante y solo imprime de manera literal el nombre de la misma, entonces para poder lograr lo anterior podemos por ejemplo, hacer un proceso de concatenación:

**Opción 1**

```
DEFINE('INCREMENTO', 20);
echo "El incremento es de: ".INCREMENTO;
```

Dando una salida como esta:

```
El incremento es de: 20
```

**Opción 2**

De acuerdo con la documentación de [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php), podemos usar el método `sprintf` el cual devuelve una cadena formateada del siguiente modo:

```
DEFINE('INCREMENTO', 20);    
$cadena = "El valor de incremento es de: \n %d";    
echo sprintf($cadena, INCREMENTO);
```

Obteniendo una salida como esta:

```
El valor de incremento es de: 
20
```

Donde como se puede observar se interpreta el salto de línea y la constante *quedaría* dentro de la cadena de texto original

**Referencias**

- [Parsear variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)